# React navigation custom screen transition

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, custom-transition

I am using **Stack Navigator** with a **transitionConfig**. In the **scene interpolator** I have defined **myCustomTransition()** which is being applied to **all the screens** in the stack.

Is is possible to have the **myCustomTransition()** applied to only **particular screens**, and the **default stack navigator transition** to the rest?

This is the **transitionConfig**:

```
const transitionConfig = () => {
    return {
        transitionSpec: {
            duration: 500,
            easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
            timing: Animated.timing,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        },

        screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
            const { scene, position, layout } = sceneProps;

            const sceneIndex = scene.index;
            const height = layout.initHeight;

            // is it possible to have a switch statement 
            switch (scene.route.routeName) {
                case 'searchScreen':
                    return myCustomTransition();

                default:
                    return defaultTransition();
            }
        },
    };
};
```

Is it possible to have a switch statement to apply **myCustomTransition()** only to the **searchScreen**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Vinay Sharma Use this

**Example:**

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        headerMode: "none",
        animationEnabed: true,
        transitionConfig: () => ({
            transitionSpec: {
                easing: Easing.bezier(.88,0.83,.82,.95),
                delay: 100,
                duration: 250,
            },
        }),
    }
);
```

Comment: Create ``createStackNavigator``, it may contain only one screen...

Comment: Hi Elango, I have mentioned that I have multiple screens. This solution is totally out of context as it nowhere specifies how to use custom transition.